# Position of data point annotation in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

Is there a way in matplotlib to specify the position of a data point annotation?

Now, it appears that the data point specified is the anchor of the bottom left corner of the annotation. Can I specify for it to be anchored at the top right?

The attached image shows my point: FDO is at [17.1, 100]. 100 is a percent, it shouldn't be above it.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass various keyword arguments corresponding to `Text` properties: see [the docs](http://matplotlib.org/api/text_api.html#matplotlib.text.Text). In your case, have you tried setting `verticalalignment='top'`? (Perhaps `center` would be more appropriate, though).

You'll have to post your code to get more detailed help, however.